# how to get all middle string in array.. remove left and right

Tags: php

I want to remove left and right texts from string like i have ( 20-100=500&101-200=1000 ) this so i want to remove from left - and right = and get result in array Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 200 ) ...

please help me on this..

```
function mid($start, $end, $str) {
    $str = substr($str, strpos($str, $start) + strlen($start));
    $data[]=substr($str, 0, strpos($str, $end));
return $data;
}
```

`print_r(mid('-', '=', '20-100=500&101-200=1000'));`

i have this but this giving me only Array ( [0] => 100 ) i want Array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 200 )

Comment: I thoroughly dislike [regular expressions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm), but this seems to need one.

Comment: Are all your input strings supposed to have the exact same format, and is the number of values to extract always two? If not, please give some more examples of what other situations might occur.

Comment: If you only want to get `[100,200]` then You don't want to get middle string, Right?

Answer (score 0):

I use these useful functions for easy string extractions.

```php
function after($this1, $inthat)
{
    if (!is_bool(strpos($inthat, $this1))) {
        return substr($inthat, strpos($inthat, $this1) + strlen($this1));
    }
    return '';
}

function before($this1, $inthat)
{
    return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $this1));
}

function between($this1, $that, $inthat)
{
    return before($that, after($this1, $inthat));
}
```

As for your problem, it's a matter of exploding, extracting, imploding.

```php
$arr = explode ('&', $str);
$brr = array_map (function ($item) {
    return between('-', '=', $item);    
}, $arr);
$result = implode ('&', $brr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mid` function you provided is designed to extract a substring from the original string that starts after `$start` and ends before `$end`. However, it only extracts the first occurrence of the substring. If you want to extract multiple occurrences between '-' and '=', you need to modify the function to iterate through the string and find all occurrences.

Here's an updated version of the function to achieve that:

```php
function mid($start, $end, $str) {
    $data = array();
    $offset = 0;
    
    while (($pos_start = strpos($str, $start, $offset)) !== false) {
        $pos_start += strlen($start);
        $pos_end = strpos($str, $end, $pos_start);
        
        if ($pos_end === false) {
            break;
        }
        
        $data[] = substr($str, $pos_start, $pos_end - $pos_start);
        $offset = $pos_end + strlen($end);
    }
    
    return $data;
}

print_r(mid('-', '=', '20-100=500&101-200=1000'));
```

This will give you the desired output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 200
)
```

The updated function will find all occurrences of substrings between '-' and '=' in the original string and return them as an array.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
    $str = "20-100=500&101-200=1000";
    preg_match_all('/-(.*?)=/', $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
?>
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/e86860

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 200
)
```